Rust heap corruption
I am reading the Rust in Action book. In one of example(namely Listing 6.3), where author describe how to decode raw memory to String and Cow.
Below is example code.
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::ffi::CStr;
use std::os::raw::c_char;

static B: [u8; 10] = [99, 97, 114, 114, 121, 116, 111, 119, 101, 108];
static C: [u8; 11] = [116, 104, 97, 110, 107, 115, 102, 105, 115, 104, 0];

fn main() {
    let a = 42;
    let b;
    let c:Cow<str>;
    unsafe {
        let b_ptr = &B as *const u8 as *mut u8;
        b = String::from_raw_parts(b_ptr, 10, 10);
        let c_ptr = &C as *const u8 as *const c_char;
        c = CStr::from_ptr(c_ptr).to_string_lossy();
    }
    println!("a: {},b: {}, c: {}", a, b, c);
}

Playground
While running above code,

With cargo run getting below error.
> cargo run --package rustinaction --example l6-3    
    Finished `dev` profile [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.04s
     Running `target\debug\examples\l6-3.exe`
a: 42,b: carrytowel, c: thanksfish
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\examples\l6-3.exe` (exit code: 0xc0000374, STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION)


On Playground,
Errors

Exited with signal 11 (SIGSEGV): segmentation violation

Standard Error

   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
    Finished `dev` profile [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.61s
     Running `target/debug/playground`

Standard Output

a: 42,b: carrytowel, c: thanksfish


When executing generated binary
> .\target\debug\examples\l6_3.exe
a: 42,b: carrytowel, c: thanksfish



What may be causing these difference in behavior?

Your program contains undefined behaviour (you can't String::from_raw_parts on static memory without leaking the string to avoid it being dropped). The compiler is literally free to do whatever it wants to do in this case, including making demons fly from your nose. Analysing what the compiler does when UB is present isn't meaningful.

Note: In case #3, when you "execute the generated binary", try following with an echo %ERRORLEVEL% (if you're using cmd) or echo $LastExitCode (in PowerShell), which should give you the same error as case #1. The playground runs Linux, explaining why the error is different from the Windows case although the meaning is the same: your program tried to free dynamic memory that was never allocated.

I can concur that this example is verbatim from Rust in Action - at least as far as I can see from the "look inside" preview available here. It called "Listing 6.3" and while the surrounding text is obfuscated (in the preview) it doesn't look like its an example for demonstrating flaws.
This code is indeed flawed. A String claims full ownership over the data it holds which includes mutability and free-ing; both of which are invalid for memory from a static (not mut) variable. The documentation for String::from_raw_parts includes safety requirements upon the pointer and sizing parameters - the one relevant here is that the memory was not allocated from the standard library's allocator - statics aren't created from an allocator.
If you don't need ownership and simply want to use a block of memory as UTF8-encoded text, use std::slice::from_raw_parts and then str::from_utf8 to get a &str referencing that data:
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::ffi::CStr;
use std::os::raw::c_char;

static B: [u8; 10] = [99, 97, 114, 114, 121, 116, 111, 119, 101, 108];
static C: [u8; 11] = [116, 104, 97, 110, 107, 115, 102, 105, 115, 104, 0];

fn main() {
    let a = 42;
    let b;
    let c:Cow<str>;
    unsafe {
        let b_ptr = &B as *const u8;
        let b_bytes = std::slice::from_raw_parts(b_ptr, 10);
        b = std::str::from_utf8(b_bytes).unwrap();
        
        let c_ptr = &C as *const u8 as *const c_char;
        c = CStr::from_ptr(c_ptr).to_string_lossy();
    }
    println!("a: {}, b: {}, c: {}", a, b, c);
}

